# How to get the pixel data in the image box under the cursor?

Tags: c#

Here is the webcam program, which can show the image by using void ProcessFrame loop 
How to get the pixel data in the image box under the cursor by using the following code?

Here are the code i capture from the website. Many thanks for the help

```
enter code here
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

using Emgu.CV;
using Emgu.CV.Structure;
using Emgu.Util;
using System.Threading; 
namespace MyOpenCV
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

private Capture _capture;
private bool _captureInProgress;


private void ProcessFrame(object sender, EventArgs arg)
{
    Image<Bgr, Byte> frame = _capture.QueryFrame();  
    captureImageBox1.Image = frame;
}

private void captureButton_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    #region if capture is not created, create it now
    if (_capture == null)
    {
        try
        {
            _capture = new Capture();
        }
        catch (NullReferenceException excpt)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excpt.Message);
        }
    }
    #endregion

    if (_capture != null)
    {
        if (_captureInProgress)
        {  //stop the capture 
            Application.Idle -= new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
            captureButton.Text = "Start Capture";
        }
        else
        {
            //start the capture 
            captureButton.Text = "Stop";
            Application.Idle += new EventHandler(ProcessFrame);
        }

        _captureInProgress = !_captureInProgress;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure I understand you? What is it that you want to acheive?

Comment: I want to base on this code..to add a new function that can show me the pixel data under the cursor

Comment: what do you mean, base on this code?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
private void pictureBox1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            var bmp = (Bitmap) pictureBox1.Image;
            var color = bmp.GetPixel(e.X, e.Y);
        }
```